# How to remap "lock screen" button to suspend

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, suspend, lock-screen

I want to remap "lock screen" button on my keyboard (it is special button, not <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combination) to "suspend" instead of "lock"

I tried to prevent screen lock all together in hope the "Settings/Keyboard/Add Custom Shortcut" would detect my "lock screen" button, but it still does not.

When I run `xev` and press the button, it displays:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  4294967288 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that if I override shortcut for lock from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to something else and then create custom shortcut with command `systemctl suspend` and keybinding <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then it somehow applies not only to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> but also to dedicated "lock button".